# Can I access a special ElasticBeanstalk EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, spray

I have a (akka spray) server application that performs two functions:

1. It responds to end-user web app requests. This is the heavy load.
2. It periodically performs light housekeeping jobs on the underlying database.

With a single instance running, everything is easy. End users' webpages are served, and through my admin webpage I can monitor and control the housekeeping jobs.

But now in order to scale to more end users, I'd like to use ElasticBeanstalk. As the end user load increases, EB will spawn more EC2 instances. However, only one of these will be the housekeeping instance, so now when I log in as an admin I need to always hit that special EC2 instance rather than being randomly assigned to whichever one has the lowest current workload.

Is there a way to do this without having a separate dedicated housekeeping EC2 outside the EB? eg, could my admin webpage or app access the special endpoint

```
http://dearEBImTheAdminPleaseGiveMeInstanceNumber1.wonderfulserver.com
```

and have it tunnel through the load balancer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It feels just messy to keep that functionality in the load balancer to me. What happens if that server gets unhealthy for example. You could possibly use the Leader instance for this and run specific commands on this only. I am not sure if you can route to it, so you might have that instance report who it is somehow.

```
container_commands:
 name of container_command:
    command: "command to run"
    leader_only: true
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands

You could make use of the fairly new Application Load Balancer and have a separate group of instance (with one in it only) and route specific traffic there (/admin).

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-application-load-balancer/

What I would do though is to do this serverless. I would have the data maintenance run in Lambda and put results in DynamoDB and then have a website in S3 that show the results. You can do it with Javascript that calls another Lambda function that fetch data from the database.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html

There is framework for it that I have read about, but not tried myself yet. https://zanon.io/posts/building-serverless-websites-on-aws-tutorial

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I certainly agree it's messy, and I'd eventually like to go serverless as you suggest, but until then I wanted to keep server costs down.

Comment: Well you have a few options above. We drastically lowered our costs when we changed a lot of our infrastructure to serverless. You only pay when you use it and it is so ridiculously cheap anyway. Aren't what you are trying to achieve going to cost more?

Comment: Yes, serverless seems better and it's what I'd like to do. But right now I have a working fat jar built on spray that does everything I need. Porting over to servless will take some developer time, and it wouldn't surprise me if the porting hits some unexpected roadblocks since serverless is still fairly new. I'm just trying to have a cost-effective deployment until we get around to the serverless version.